# Searching text file fails if date format it not met

Tags: python-2.7

If I run the below it lets me parse through a text file, but wont skip over a line if it doesn't match the time format and stops. Need some direction on how to get the script to continue searching through the file if the date format isn't met:

```
17:14:26.442 words words words words words

17:15:32.533 words words words words words

17:16:26.442 words words words words words

 Line with no time: words words words words words (***Fails here because time format is not met)***

17:18:26.442 words words words words words

17:19:32.533 words words words words words

17:20:26.442 words words words words words

17:21:32.533 words words words words words



begin = raw_input('Enter beginning time in this format hh:mm:ss:sss. Example 17:00:00.000  \n')
endtime = raw_input('Enter ending time in this format hh:mm:ss:sss. Example 18:00:00.000 \n')   

start = dt.strptime(begin,'%H:%M:%S.%f')        
end = dt.strptime(endtime,'%H:%M:%S.%f')
f = open('test.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
        ts = dt.strptime(line.split()[0],'%H:%M:%S.%f')
        if ts >= start and ts <= end:
            print line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid option for searching by time:

```
start = raw_input("What time was the call? ")
end = raw_input("What time did the call end? ")

with open('2ndtest.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
            ts = line.split()
            try:
                if ts[3] >= start:
                    print line      
            except IndexError:
                continue
                print line  
            if end in line:
                    break
```